# how works direct message in py-cord on_member_join()

Tags: python, discord, pycord

Unfortunately I can't find on the internet how the direct message at on_member_join works.
Could someone please help me

Here is my code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):

    guild = member.guild
    if (
            guild.system_channel is not None
    ):
        await guild.system_channel.send(f"Servus {member.mention} herzlich wilkomma auf {guild.name}!")
        'Here should be the code for the direct message '
```

I have tried older code which unfortunately no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pycord` documentation is a good place to look. The [`discord.Member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Member) object has a [`send`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Member.send) method which you can use to send a direct message to.

So,

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):

    guild = member.guild
    if (
            guild.system_channel is not None
    ):
        await guild.system_channel.send(f"Servus {member.mention} herzlich wilkomma auf {guild.name}!")
        try:
            await member.send(
                "Check out the pycord docs here: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/index.html"
            )
        except discord.Forbidden:
            # can't message the user directly - nothing we can do about it
            # they might have random DMs turned off
            pass
```